# Azure point-to-site vpn with MFA - Authorization working but no connection after that

Tags: azure-networking, point-to-site-vpn

I've setup a point-to-site vpn on Azure using RADIUS authentication and multi-factor authentication. The authentication is all working and I can see NPS granting access and I'm getting authentication requests on my phone (call or app) and Access Accepted events in the AzureMfa eventlog, but then nothing...

The Azure VPN app just times out without connecting. I'm getting a 619 error in the VPN client's event log but I'm using SSTP so it should all be going over port 443 (and i've disabled the firewall for testing anyway).

I don't think there are connection logs in Azure (please correct me if wrong) for the p2s VPN so I'm stuck now, any help is greatly appreciated.